# Not able to keep table border color to white in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have created simple table inside a table with border

```
//Top Table
<table border="5" bordercolor="#36C1DF"  class="topCss" >
    //rest table 
     <tr> 
       <td>
         //This table Border is the problem in IE
        <TABLE  class="innerCss">   
       </td>
      </tr>
     // And my below are css settings
     .topCss
     {
       border-collapse: separate;
       border-style: solid;
       border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
       border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
      }
     .innerCss
      {
           border:2px solid #ffffff; 
      }
```

Actually above table border color `white` is working fine in Chrome and FireFox but in IE is actually looking black insted of `white` color.

[image: This image border is in Chrom]

[image: This image border is in IE]

Please help how to get white color border in IE-9

Comment: USE: <table style="border: 2px solid #fff;">

Comment: I have tried that it did not work ..

Comment: Which IE version you are talking about?

Comment: I check this in IE and it is working... fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awtzq835/. Is there any other class which is over-writting from CSS?

Comment: To check the overwrites.. use important property in style itself.. LIKE : <table style="border: 2px solid #fff !important;">

Answer (score 0):

use css:

```
table{
border:2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

If you want td color white also , then  add this code more:

```
table tr td{
border:2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Try these total code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>


 body{ 
 background:#000;
 color:#fff;}
.topCss
     {
        border:5px solid #36C1DF;
       border-collapse: separate;
       border-style: solid;
       border-bottom-right-radius:12px;
       border-bottom-left-radius:12px;
      }
     .innerCss
      {
           border:2px solid #ffffff; 
      }   
     </style> 
</head>

<body>

<!--     
//Top Table-->
<table class="topCss" >
  <!--  //rest table -->
     <tr> 
       <td>
       <!--  //This table Border is the problem in IE-->
        <TABLE  class="innerCss" >   
        <tr><td> cell 1 </td> <td>cell 2</td></tr>
        </TABLE>
       </td>
      </tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited my question please have a look.. I tried this it didnt work

Comment: Thats causing some other problems I mean other components in the body are getting effected... Actually when when I am not using inline css its not effecting at all in any browser.. I mean minmum  I need to add `border='2' bordercolor='somecolor' `..

Answer (score 0):

Please udate your code with

```
<table bordercolor='white' style="border-style:none;">
```

please remove border='2'. Try this, should work

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but I'd suggest that you skip HTML styling and use CSS (preferably not inline):

```
<table style="border: 2px solid #fff;">
    //rest table
```

Note: Remove the `border` and `bordercolor` HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you :

```
<!--     
//Top Table-->
<table class="topCss" style="border: 5px solid #36C1DF;" >
  <!--  //rest table -->
     <tr  > 
       <td >
       <!--  //This table Border is the problem in IE-->
        <TABLE  class="innerCss" style="border: 2px solid #fff;" >   
        <tr ><td> cell 1 </td> <td>cell 2</td></tr>
        </TABLE>
       </td>
      </tr>


</table>
```